# Seems like right margins in answer texts need to be increased

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, mathjax, design

It is a very minor thing but still - it seems that answer texts have zero right margin which shows somehow unpleasantly with colored background of accepted answers:

[image]

(This is with latest Chrome on Windows 10 x64)

Do you agree that it would be better to increase it?

Comment: No amount of extra margin is going to solve this. The problem is that the final width of MathJax content is not known beforehand so that the browser could use it when deciding line breaks.

Comment: There's a last Fermat theorem joke waiting to be made here.

Answer (score 2):

the formula bumping into the right margin shown in the OP is indeed unpleasant, but it seems to happen rarely; typically the layout looks OK to me:[image]

the asymmetric layout in the green box, with a large margin at the left and zero margin at the right, does not strike me as unpleasant.

Comment: As @EmilJeřábek points out, this seems to be mathjax-related